# Pytest - How to make sure mutable fixture stay unchanged?

Tags: python, pytest

I have some dummy fixtures:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def base():
    return {
        'name': 'John',
        'surname': 'Snow'
    }


@pytest.fixture
def data(base):
    base['name'] = 'Alfred'
    return base
```

Also there is test function:

```
def test_function(data, base):
    assert data == base
```

The result of the test is **True**. But it is unexpected result. As you could guess the problem is that in **data** fixture the **name** field was overwritten.

This bug can be solved like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def data(base):
    base = copy.deepcopy(base)
    base['name'] = 'Alfred'
    return base
```

But may there is more standart way?

Comment: No, copying the `dict` is the standard way. You could use `dict.copy()` instead of `copy.deepcopy()`, though.

Comment: It is also a good practice to not use side effects to change fixtures. A future you will appreciate this. Remember future you knows where you lived and is a little bit crazier.